# Do offline generated addresses need to be activated at the node to be used? What are the activated commands

Tags: tezos-client

Do offline generated addresses need to be activated at the node to be used? What are the activated commands? When I use the offline generated address for transfer,  I reported the following error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Addresses must be revealed first by sending a transaction to it. Sending a transaction to it will save the related public key (the « manager » in the error message) in the context. It is implemented in this way because saving in the context and keep data in the context has a cost.
You can find more information [here](https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtouse.html#transfers-and-receipts).

Comment: I once transferred two transactions to tz1imwhmv5er5zunepwskktkvifkchqzkgm, but there was still an error

Comment: @danny-willems That's not correct. Address only need to be revealed in order to send FROM them, not to receive. You can send as much as you want to an unrevealed address. The first transaction sent to a new address must pay an activation (ie: burn) fee which is for the associated context costs. Once you want to send FROM an address, you  must reveal it.

Answer (score 0):

No, generated addresses do not need to be activated (except fundraiser addresses). However, the first operation shell your sign and broadcast must include a reveal operation. This operation reveals the public key associated to a public key hash, so others can verify the signatures associated to the public key hash.